# CloudKit wegservice method not allowed

Tags: web-services, cloudkit

Im trying to use the cloud kit web service but i keep getting 'Method not allowed'
Why is this?

curl "https://api.apple-cloudkit.com/database/1/iCloud.nl.igeni.MYIDHERE/development/users/current?ckAPITokenMYTOKENHERE"
Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot private or public. Also, `caller` is now preferred over `current`.
The correct url is:
`https://api.apple-cloudkit.com/database/1/iCloud.nl.igeni.MYIDHERE/development/public/users/caller?ckAPITokenMYTOKENHERE`

See the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/FetchCurrentUserIdentity.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH27-SW1